# company ID not passing through simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, simple-form-for

I've been stuck for a while now with this relationship problem and I was wondering if someone can spot where I'm going wrong.

I have a user-company-introductions relationship (similar to a patient-doctor-appointment relationship).

I have it setup so that the simple_form_for CompanyIntroduction appears as a popup Modal, rendered through a partial.

**The problem** is that when I go to submit/save the form, I get the error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in User::CompanyIntroductionsController#create
>
> Couldn't find Company with
> 'id'=

```
>@introduction.company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
```

Why the heck isn't my company_id passing through the form?

#### Migration

```
class CreateCompanyIntroductions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :company_introductions do |t|
   t.integer :status, null: false, default: 0
   t.string :user_name
   t.string :user_email
   t.text :message
  
   t.references :company, index: true
   t.belongs_to :user, index: true

   t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

#### User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :company_introductions, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :companies, through: :company_introductions
end
```

#### Company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :company_introductions
 has_many :users, through: :company_introductions
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_introductions   
end
```

#### CompanyIntroduction.rb

```
class CompanyIntroduction < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :company 
end
```

#### User/CompanyIntroductionController

```
class User::CompanyIntroductionsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @introduction = CompanyIntroduction.all
 end 

 def create
  @introduction = CompanyIntroduction.create(intro_params)
  @introduction.user = current_user
  @introduction.company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  if @introduction.save
   flash[:success] = "Introduction request sent"
  else
   flash[:error] = @introduction.errors.full_messages
  end
   redirect_back(fallback_location: user_companies_path)
 end

 def intro_params
  params.require(:company_introduction).permit(:status, :username, :user_email, :message)
 end
end
```

## And the display pages...

```
...

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCompanyIntroduction" >
 Create Introduction
</button>
<%= render partial: '/user/company_introductions/create_modal', locals:{entity: @company }  %>

...
```

#### Create Modal Partial

```
<%= simple_form_for [:user, CompanyIntroduction.new(company_id: entity.id)] do |f| %>
 <div class="modal fade" id="createCompanyIntroduction" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createCompanyIntroduction">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Request introduction with <%= entity.name %>, id: <%=entity.id%></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= f.label :user_name, "Your name *"%>
      <%= f.input :user_name, label: false, placeholder: "#{current_user.full_name}" %>
  
       <%= f.label :user_email, "Email *" %>
       <%= f.input :user_email, label: false, placeholder: "#{current_user.email}" %>
         
        <%= f.label :message, "Why do you want to meet? *" %>
        <%= f.text_area :message, class:"form-control", rows: 4, label: false, style: 'resize:vertical;', maxlength: '1500' %>
          
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

       <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems like you need to add company_id to permitted params

Comment: Where should this `params[:company_id]` be coming from, it's not part of the form itself, is it part of the url that gets submitted?

Comment: You ask for the user email in the form but you do not use it (you use current_user in create). And you don't ask for a company_id in the form. Which company will the introduction belong to?

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I see now what I did wrong, I was trying to pass the company_id as part of the url and not aspart of the form. Got it working using the hidden_field. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're passing the entity to your partial you can add a hidden field for compnay_id in the form and assign its value to entity id.  My changes to the partial would be as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:user, CompanyIntroduction.new] do |f| %>
    <!--rest of code -->
    <%=f.input :company_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: entity.id} %>
    <!-- rest of code -->
<% end %>
```

In the controller, add :company_id to the list of permitted params and comment out this line in the create method.

```
#@introduction.company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
```

Hope that helps.